# Working with generic definitions in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I am working with limits and I am unable to prove the following

```
definition func :: "real ⇒ real"
where "func = real"

lemma "(λh. (func (x+h))) -- 0 --> (func (x))"
unfolding func_def
apply (auto intro!: tendsto_eq_intros)
```

However if I replace the definition of func to

```
definition func :: "real ⇒ real"
where "func x = x"
```

the lemma is solved.

How can I solve this lemma when working with generic definitions?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, here the problem is that the function `real` has just a generic (overloaded) syntax, i.e., `real :: 'a => real`, but it is not necessarily defined for all possible types `'a`. This is easily seen when using `find_theorems`: when searching for lemmas on `real :: nat => real`, you get plenty of results whereas searching for `real :: real => real` doesn't give you a single result.

```
find_theorems "real :: real => real"
find_theorems "real :: nat => real"
```

Consequently, you can not even prove a simple lemma like `func x = x`, since it is not specified that  `real :: real => real` really is the identity function.

Comment: Would it not be possible to solve the lemma without unfolding the definition of the function then?